# css equal div height

Tags: css, html, height

I have this html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="left">left<br/>asdfa</div>
   <div id="right">right</div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div> 
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#wrapper {
   width: 400px;
   background-color:green;
   display:table;
}
#left {
   display:table-cell;
   float:left;
   width:100px;
   background: blue;
}
#right {
   height:auto;
   width:100px;
   background: red;
   float:right;
}
```

How to make the right div to fit the height of the wrapper div ??

Comment: Did you try "height: 100%" ?

Comment: i tried all existing heights and it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 ways to do it:

1) set equal height for all 3 DIVs examle:

```
#wrapper {
   width: 400px;
   background-color:green;
   display:table;
    height:50px;
}
#left {
   display:table-cell;
   float:left;
   width:100px;
   background: blue;
    height:50px;
}
#right {
   width:100px;
   background: red;
   float:right;
    height:50px;
}
```

Demo: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codeMonk/GemEn/2/)**

2)

add :

```
#right {
   height:100%;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

Demo: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codeMonk/GemEn/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxUz4/)

```
#right {
   text-align: right; 
   display:table-cell; 
   height:100%;
   width:100px;
   background: red;
   position: relative; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this out, tell me if it worked or not.

style.css

```
#right {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100px;
background: red;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: you want the right div to have the same height and cover over the wrapper like blue in this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/62DQ8/

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery might be a bit overkill if the CSS fixes above work for you, but the guys at [Zurb](http://zurb.com/) showcased a pretty neat way of equalling out the height of divs:

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1358

> Here's some example HTML of a grid snippet and a block-grid snippet.
> You'll notice a few data attributes, data-match-height and
> data-height-watch. These are used to scope the parent of the elements
> you want as the same height and to mark the children that will look to
> match heights.
>
> ```
> <div class="row" data-match-height>
>   <div data-height-watch class="small-3 columns" style="background: pink;">
>     <p>Some text...</p>
>   </div>
>   <div data-height-watch class="small-6 columns" style="background: orange;">
>     <p>Some text...</p>
>     <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
>   </div>
>   <div data-height-watch class="small-3 columns" style="background: lightblue;">
>     <p>Some text...</p>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> From here, I created a some JS that will do the magic:
>
> ```
> $("[data-match-height]").each(function() {
>
>   var parentRow = $(this),
>       childrenCols = $(this).find("[data-height-watch]"),
>       childHeights = childrenCols.map(function(){ return $(this).height(); }).get(),
>       tallestChild = Math.max.apply(Math, childHeights);
>
>   childrenCols.css('min-height', tallestChild);
>
> });
> ```
>
> You can include this JS in app.js under the JS links at the bottom of your pages.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
       <div id="left">left<br/>asdfa</div>
       <div id="right">right</div>    
       <div style="clear:both"></div> 
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: green;
    display: table;
}
#left {
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
#right {
    background-color: red;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62DQ8/19/)**

Answer (score 0):

This many updates are not required.

Only put **display:table-cell** in **#right** css. that's it. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

new answare using javascript

FIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/62DQ8/62/

ADD this in the `<head>HERE</head>`

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var h = document.getElementById("wrapper").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("right").style.height = h + "px";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this equal height jquery

```
setHeight($('.wrapper > div'));

function setHeight(col) {
    var $col = $(col);

    var $maxHeight = 0;
    $col.each(function () {
        var $thisHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
        if ($thisHeight > $maxHeight) {
            $maxHeight = $thisHeight;
        }
    });
    $col.height($maxHeight);
}
```